# Memory Leaks in Embedded Jetty during load testing

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

I am using the embedded jetty. I have it deployed on a unix machine, I am monitoring the memory using the top command. I wrote a class that would send 10 requests per second to the Server. When the number of requests reaches 16000, the engine start throwing an exception: Memory allocation failed during query processing. The engine performs sql queries fro every request that is sent.

I used the verbose option and I noticed the increase in memory consumption:

0 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
1401.581: [GC [PSYoungGen: 640K->128K(768K)] 126729K->126249K(130816K), 0.0004840 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
1401.585: [GC [PSYoungGen: 640K->96K(768K)] 126761K->126305K(130816K), 0.0004510 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
1401.590: [GC [PSYoungGen: 605K->128K(768K)] 126814K->126379K(130816K), 0.0004500 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
1401.595: [GC [PSYoungGen: 640K->80K(768K)] 126891K->126419K(130816K), 0.0004270 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]

I use jetty.xml to configure the embedded jetty server, I am using a queuedthreadpool, with the following values:

minThreads:10
maxThreads:20

Can anyone help me identify the memory leak? Is it related to the way I am accessing the database? Is it related to Jetty?

Below is the main class (Took a sample from eclipsepedia :(http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty)

```
public class PPTEST {

private static String fileName = "*************/properties.conf";
private static Properties p = new Properties();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try {
        loadProperties(fileName);

        Resource fileserver_xml = Resource.newResource("********/jetty.xml");


        XmlConfiguration configuration = new            XmlConfiguration(fileserver_xml.getInputStream());
        Server server = (Server) configuration.configure();

        server.setHandler(new HandlerApple());

        server.start();
        server.join()

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static void loadProperties(String fileName)
        throws IOException {

    FileInputStream propsFile = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    p.load(propsFile);
    propsFile.close();
}
```

}

---

And this is the HandlerApple Class:

public class HandlerApple extends AbstractHandler {

```
//Properties p = new Properties();
private String CHARACTERS = "0123456789ABCDEF";
private String OK = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK";
Properties config;
public org.apache.log4j.Logger logger;
private String fileName = "****************/gprs-properties.conf";
private String smsformat = "*****************/smsformat.prop";
private Connection dbConn;
private HashMap hpSystem;
private HashMap hpConf;
private String prefix;
private String mobfiltering;
private String resp600;
private String resp601;
private String resp602;
private String resp603;
private String resp604;
private String resp605;
private String resp607;
private String resp608;
private String resp612;
private String resp613;
private String resp611;
private String resp606;
private String resp666;
private String ipH;
private String portH;
private String timeoutH;
private String trpmC;
private String ttpipC;
private String lpdC;
private String igprsC;
private String first_timeout;
private String second_timeout;
private PreparedStatement pstmt;
private ResultSet rs;
Random randomGenerator = new Random();

HandlerApple() {
    DatabaseSingleton d = new DatabaseSingleton();
    try {
        org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure("************/log4j.properties");
        logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(HandlerApple.class.getName());
        logger.info("Contructor Level");
        dbConn = d.getConnection();
        hpSystem = loadConfigFile(fileName);
        hpConf = loadConfigFile(smsformat);
        prefix = (String) hpSystem.get("prefixes");
        mobfiltering = (String) hpSystem.get("mobile-filtering");
        resp600 = (String) hpConf.get("600");
        resp601 = (String) hpConf.get("601");
        resp602 = (String) hpConf.get("602");
        resp603 = (String) hpConf.get("603");
        resp604 = (String) hpConf.get("604");
        resp605 = (String) hpConf.get("605");
        resp607 = (String) hpConf.get("607");
        resp608 = (String) hpConf.get("608");
        resp612 = (String) hpConf.get("612");
        resp613 = (String) hpConf.get("613");
        resp611 = (String) hpConf.get("611");
        resp606 = (String) hpConf.get("606");
        resp666 = (String) hpConf.get("666");
        ipH = (String) hpSystem.get("module-1.ip");
        portH = (String) hpSystem.get("module-1.port");
        timeoutH = (String) hpSystem.get("module-1.timeout");
        trpmC = (String) hpSystem.get("trpm");
        ttpipC = (String) hpSystem.get("ttpip");
        lpdC = (String) hpSystem.get("lpd");
        igprsC = (String) hpSystem.get("igprs.trpm");
        first_timeout = (String) hpSystem.get("timeout.1");
        second_timeout = (String) hpSystem.get("timeout.2");
        logger.info("==================================================================");
        logger.info("Clearing maps");
        logger.info("==================================================================");
        hpSystem.clear();
        hpConf.clear();
        pstmt = null;
        rs = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



 public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

   try{
   //Some code

   }catch (Exception e){
   //
   }

   finally {
            response.flushBuffer();
            if (pstmt != null) {
                try {
                    pstmt.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(HandlerApple.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,   ex);
                }
            }
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(HandlerApple.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }



        }

 }
```

---

I am using the DatabaseSingleton class:

```
public class DatabaseSingleton {
    //Static instance of connection, only one will ever exist

    private Connection connection = null;
    //Returns single instance of connection

    public Connection getConnection() {
        //If instance has not been created yet, create it
        if (connection == null) {
            initConnection();
        }
        return connection;
    }


    private void initConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver");
            Properties p=new Properties();
            loadProperties("************/gprs-properties.conf", p);
            String dburl = p.getProperty("gprs.informix.url");
            String dbuser = p.getProperty("gprs.informix.user");
            String dbpass = p.getProperty("gprs.informix.password");
            connection =
                    DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, dbuser, dbpass);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
private void loadProperties(String fileName, Properties p)
            throws IOException {

        FileInputStream propsFile = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        p.load(propsFile);
        propsFile.close();




    }
```

---

After the exception is thrown and I stop the engine, the following gets printed (using the verbose option):

```
 Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 832K, used 288K [0xb4d60000, 0xb4e60000, 0xb4e60000)
  eden space 640K, 32% used [0xb4d60000,0xb4d94060,0xb4e00000)
  from space 192K, 41% used [0xb4e30000,0xb4e44010,0xb4e60000)
  to   space 192K, 0% used [0xb4e00000,0xb4e00000,0xb4e30000)
 PSOldGen        total 219520K, used 212479K [0x94e60000, 0xa24c0000, 0xb4d60000)
  object space 219520K, 96% used [0x94e60000,0xa1ddfc50,0xa24c0000)
 PSPermGen       total 16384K, used 8145K [0x90e60000, 0x91e60000, 0x94e60000)
  object space 16384K, 49% used [0x90e60000,0x91654420,0x91e60000)
```

---

The exception trace is the following:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Memory allocation failed during query processing.
        at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:373)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.a(IfxSqli.java:3208)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.E(IfxSqli.java:3518)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2353)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2269)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executePrepare(IfxSqli.java:1153)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.e(IfxPreparedStatement.java:318)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.a(IfxPreparedStatement.java:298)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.<init>(IfxPreparedStatement.java:168)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.h(IfxSqliConnect.java:5918)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.prepareStatement(IfxSqliConnect.java:1999)
        at pinpayhttp.HandlerApple.checkIP(HandlerApple.java:520)
        at pinpayhttp.HandlerApple.handle(HandlerApple.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:596)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1068)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:807)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:426)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:528)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException
        at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:373)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.E(IfxSqli.java:3523)
```

### ... 21 more

### jmap -histo:live 12469

After the Memory allocation failed exception:

```
    1:        209324       76966096  [Ljava.lang.Object;
       2:         12971       45337576  [B
       3:       1537794       24604704  java.lang.Integer
       4:        172537       13265160  [C
       5:         32768       10223616  com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli
       6:         32767        6291264  com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement
       7:        207565        4981560  java.util.Vector
       8:         39807        4056792  [I
       9:        160921        3862104  java.lang.String
      10:         32767        3145632  com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSet
      11:         19329        2202664  <constMethodKlass>
      12:         21846        2097216  com.informix.jdbc.IfxColumnInfo
      13:         19329        1550760  <methodKlass>
      14:         32767        1310680  com.informix.jdbc.IfxResultSetMetaData
      15:         30807        1118264  <symbolKlass>
      16:          1400         843192  <constantPoolKlass>
      17:         10901         784872  com.informix.jdbc.IfxChar
      18:          1400         597000  <instanceKlassKlass>
      19:          1276         542848  <constantPoolCacheKlass>
      20:         32774         524384  java.lang.StringBuffer
      21:         10923         524304  com.informix.jdbc.IfxRowColumn
      22:          1274         326536  <methodDataKlass>
      23:          2258         181760  [S
      24:          1563         150048  java.lang.Class
      25:          2147         117904  [[I
      26:          2820          67680  java.util.HashMap$Entry
      27:          1936          46464  java.lang.StackTraceElement
      28:           134          42880  <objArrayKlassKlass>
      29:           319          42456  [Ljava.util.HashMap$Entry;
      30:          1478          35472  java.util.Hashtable$Entry
      31:           293          18752  org.eclipse.jetty.io.BufferCache$CachedBuffer
      32:           212          16008  [Ljava.lang.String;
      33:           445          14240  org.eclipse.jetty.util.StringMap$Node
      34:            76          14000  [Ljava.util.Hashtable$Entry;
      35:           163          13040  [Lorg.eclipse.jetty.util.StringMap$Node;
      36:           301          12040  java.util.HashMap
      37:           358          11456  java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
      38:           308           9856  java.lang.ref.SoftReference
      39:            89           8816  [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;
      40:           140           7840  org.eclipse.jetty.io.ByteArrayBuffer
      41:           195           7800  java.sql.SQLException
      42:           192           6144  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment
      43:            81           5184  java.lang.reflect.Constructor
      44:            10           4896  [[Ljava.lang.Object;
      45:           294           4704  java.util.jar.Attributes$Name
      46:           195           4680  java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync
      47:            78           4368  java.net.URL
      48:           161           3864  java.lang.ref.WeakReference
      49:           192           3440  [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry;
      50:           143           3432  sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier
      51:            85           3400  java.math.BigInteger
      52:           138           3312  java.util.ArrayList
      53:            66           3168  java.beans.MethodDescriptor
      54:            98           3136  java.lang.ref.Finalizer
      55:            56           3136  java.security.Provider$Service
  56:           124           2976  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni.QName
  57:            24           2880  java.net.SocksSocketImpl
  58:           118           2832  java.security.Provider$ServiceKey
  59:             8           2560  <typeArrayKlassKlass>
  60:             6           2464  [Lcom.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni.QName;
  61:            61           2440  java.util.Hashtable
  62:            22           2288  sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl
  63:            25           2248  [Z
  64:             2           2248  [Lorg.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpStatus$Code;
  65:           140           2240  java.util.jar.Attributes
  66:            70           2240  java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry
  67:             7           2120  [J
  68:             1           2048  [Lorg.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator$Status;
  69:            36           2016  java.nio.DirectByteBuffer
  70:           251           2008  java.lang.Object
  71:            27           1944  java.util.jar.JarFile$JarFileEntry
  72:            21           1680  java.lang.reflect.Method
  73:            16           1664  java.lang.Thread
  74:            65           1560  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry
  75:            19           1520  [Ljava.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry;
  76:            14           1456  [[Ljava.lang.String;
  77:            36           1440  sun.misc.Cleaner
  78:            30           1440  java.util.ResourceBundle$CacheKey
  79:            22           1408  java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
  80:            35           1400  sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader
  81:            73           1360  [Ljava.lang.Class;
  82:            27           1296  java.lang.Package
  83:            81           1296  java.util.HashMap$EntrySet
  84:            27           1296  java.util.jar.JarFile
  85:            50           1200  sun.security.util.DerInputBuffer
  86:            50           1200  sun.security.util.DerValue
  87:            30           1200  java.util.ResourceBundle$BundleReference
  88:            50           1200  sun.security.x509.RDN
  89:            47           1128  java.net.InetSocketAddress
  90:            47           1128  org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpStatus$Code
  91:            47           1128  java.io.ExpiringCache$Entry
  92:            10           1120  <klassKlass>
  93:            46           1104  org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator$Status
  94:             8           1088  java.text.DecimalFormat
  95:            45           1080  java.net.Inet4Address
  96:             2           1056  [Ljava.lang.Integer;
  97:            22           1056  sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor
  98:             1           1040  [Lcom.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.models.ContentModelValidator;
  99:             1           1040  [Lsun.text.normalizer.UnicodeSet;
 100:             1           1040  [Lcom.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.DatatypeValidator;
 101:             8           1000  [Ljava.beans.MethodDescriptor;
 102:            41            984  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.SymbolTable$Entry
 103:            12            960  [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment;
 104:            30            960  java.util.ResourceBundle$LoaderReference
 105:            40            960  com.informix.util.IfxMessage$bundleMap
 106:            58            928  <compiledICHolderKlass>
 107:            28            896  java.util.zip.Inflater
 108:             8            896  java.util.GregorianCalendar
 109:            36            864  java.nio.DirectByteBuffer$Deallocator
 110:             9            864  sun.util.calendar.Gregorian$Date
 111:            52            832  java.security.Provider$UString
 112:            50            800  sun.security.util.DerInputStream
 113:            50            800  sun.security.x509.AVA
 114:            50            800  [Lsun.security.x509.AVA;
 115:            33            792  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl
 116:            16            768  java.util.LinkedHashMap
 117:            23            736  java.util.Locale
 118:            30            720  java.security.Provider$EngineDescription
 119:            18            720  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLSimpleType
 120:             1            704  [Lcom.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.SymbolTable$Entry;
 121:             2            640  <arrayKlassKlass>
 122:            16            640  java.util.WeakHashMap$Entry
 123:            39            624  java.util.regex.Pattern$CharPropertyNames$1
 124:            19            608  java.io.ObjectStreamField
 125:            15            600  sun.nio.cs.ISO_8859_1$Decoder
 126:            25            600  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.XMLStringBuffer
 127:            12            576  java.nio.HeapByteBuffer
 128:            36            576  sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl
 129:            12            576  sun.security.x509.X500Name
 130:            11            528  java.util.Properties
 131:            22            528  java.util.Date
 132:            22            528  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni.XMLString
 133:            22            528  sun.security.x509.OIDMap$OIDInfo
 134:            22            528  [Ljava.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
 135:             8            512  java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols
 136:            21            504  java.security.AccessControlContext
 137:            21            504  sun.security.x509.AVAKeyword
 138:             7            504  org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.DirectNIOBuffer
 139:            31            496  java.io.FileDescriptor
 140:            12            480  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
 141:            15            480  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLElementDecl
 142:            19            456  java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap
 143:             7            448  java.text.SimpleDateFormat
 144:             8            448  org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.IndirectNIOBuffer
 145:             9            432  sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo
 146:            17            408  com.informix.msg.bundleMap
 147:             5            400  java.net.URI

    Total       2644614      206176808
```

Can anyone help? I just need some guidance...

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your memory limit appears to be very low for a high load. I would try `-mx1g` as a start, more if you have more memory (and a 64-bit JVM).

Can you print the exact exception as the message can be important?

Comment: Hi Pete, I edited my post so it shows the exception I am getting. In addtion, here is the memory result of the top command: Mem:   8308560k total,  7641496k used,   667064k free. So if I use the -mx1g option I should be fine right?

Comment: Here's how I am starting the engine:
java -verbose:gc -Xloggc:gc.txt -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3000 -Xms128m -Xmx512m -server -XX:NewRatio=512m -cp ...., where should I add the -mx1g option?

Comment: I would use just `java -verbose:gc -Xloggc:gc.txt -XX:+PrintGCDetails -mx1g`  I am not sure that triggering a gc every 3 seconds is a good idea, `-server` should be on by default and IMHO the NewRatio should be as low as possible (even less than 1) e.g. I have run systems with an 8 GB eden size c.f. yours is 832K

Comment: Okay Pete, I did that and I am testing it now. The strange thing is that the free memory is always decreasing, as if the resources aren't being freed.

Comment: Your total heap used is 221M so I amd surprised its not closer to 512m that you set.  If you have a 64-bit JVM, try `-mx4g` which is half you memory.  Then see how it behaves and reduce it when you see it using too much.

Comment: This is possible as the application warms up.  Only the free space after a full GC is worth looking at.

Comment: If you do have a memory leak, it should become more obvious with more memory. Use jmap to get a `-histo:live` to see what objects are being used the most.

Comment: Alright Pete, I will perform the testing and post the results once I'm done. Again, thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I can see you are using a 32-bit JVM. Its worth nothing that 64-bit JVMs can use 32-bit references up to 32 GB of memory.  You may be better off (as the overhead is not as much as some people think)

Comment: Hi Pete, I used the histo command and I listed a part of the output in the main post, is there anything wrong I should look into?

Comment: According to the histo, you are using < 10 MB when you heap has a maximum of 1 GB.  This is useful as a starting position and I would subtract these figures from any increase you see as the program runs.

Comment: Hi Pete, I updated the histo results, I ran the command just when the engine threw the exception, do you see any notable difference?

Comment: The package which show up the most is `com.informix.jdbc` in the histo and its the package which failed.  If you are not closing all you statements and resultssets these will accumulate http://blog.shinetech.com/2007/08/04/how-to-close-jdbc-resources-properly-every-time/

Comment: I close them in the finally block, but I dont close the dbConn, because I'm using it as a Singleton, what do you suggest? Should I take another approach?

Comment: It appears you have retained 32767 PreparedStatement and ResultsSets. Closing them should be enough, but I would try closing the connection for every 1000 queries and see if that makes a difference (you shouldn't have to)

Comment: Pete thanks for your continuous help. I will close the connection for every 1000 queries and see how it behaves. I would have opted for something different than the Singleton but I would have ended up with multiple db connections, anyhow I will test and get back with the results, again, thanks a lot my friend.

Comment: Pete I did as we agreed and it has reached the 84k for now, going strong but the free memory is getting reduced. I guess I'm 80% there, thanks a lot for the push, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: You need to do another `jmap -histo:live` when the free memory is low.

Answer (score 0):

Make a heap dump ("jmap -dump:live,file=yourdump.hprof ") and look
at it using an analyizing tool. Try
http://www.dr-brenschede.de/bheapsampler/
or
http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

The 32767 Prepared Statements in your "jmap -histo" look strange enough, but you need to find out what is keeping them.

Comment: I will look into it using the command you suggested, thanks for your help my friend